# Openvpn when connected, local IP of Pi not reachable

Tags: openvpn, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b running the latest Raspian image. Openvpn is configured to start at bootup as a service and connect to a vpn for a nfs share.

When the Pi is connected through the vpn, I can no longer access my webmin and oscam page etc by visiting 192.168.x.x from one of my local machines.

How can I fix this?

The pi gets an 10.0.X.X address and the 192.168.X.X address becomes unreachable

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: both routers had the same subnet. Changed one of them and now everything works!